# How can I make windows installer (WiX) always think it is running an upgrade or new install?

Tags: wix

This is an installer for a SQL database. It really does not change anything on the local computer but connects to a database to make changes.

The user could be upgrading 3 different database servers from one computer so they should be able to run it 3 times utilizing the same dialogs.

I would like the installer to always show the same custom dialogs I have setup. I do not want it to go into the maintenance dialog.

I have set the MajorUpgrade tag as so, which the documentation says covers "AllowSameVersionUpgrades"

```
 <MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="yes" />
```

I tried changing the dialogs "Next" buttons like so. NewDBDlg is a custom screen.

```
 <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="NewDBDlg">1</Publish>
 <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="NewDBDlg">1</Publish>
```

This kind of works but it gets to the last "VerifyReadyDlg" screen and it is mostly blank with only a "Back" and "Cancel" button.

Am I heading in the right direction or should I try something else like remove the install as part of the installation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes I need to make an .MSI that isn't really a traditional installer. It's more of a utility then an installed application.  Microsoft does this sometimes with their Microsoft Fix it [series of utilities](https://support2.microsoft.com/fixit/).

This is an uncommon scenario but can be done by suppressing certain Windows Installer standard actions:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RegisterProduct Suppress="yes" />
  <PublishFeatures Suppress="yes" />
  <PublishProduct Suppress="yes" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Because the product is never registered with the installer service there is no repair, uninstall, upgrade, maintenance and so on.

Comment: To download a sample Fix It go here: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9850239 _You probably don't want to run it!_

Answer (score 2):

The reason it goes into maintenance mode is because you have the same ProductCode every time, so changing the ProductCode for each build would work. But then you are filling the system with installed products. So...

If you're willing to use the MajorUpgrade element and increment the ProductVersion (and change ProductCode) for each build of the MSI, then a major upgrade shouldf work. Every install will be a complete fresh install, but if the older product happens to be there then it will uninstall it. Then you'll only ever have one antry in Program&Features. Otherwise Chris's solution is good.

This doesn't really seem like the kind of thing that Windows Installer was designed for.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this would probably be better built as a utility. It seemed like an easy path at first. Its part of setup, looks like our other installers...

Comment: I agree it's somewhat subversive and not for the uninformed. Still, I've seen MSFT do it and there don't seem to be any prohibitions or ICE tests to challenge it.   You do get a lot of the benefits of MSI doing it this way.  Still, I'd call this only do it if you know what you are doing and a custom utility to execute SQL scripts would probably be better.