# Is there a way to create an MSI with WiX that doesn't register a program with windows?

Tags: wix

What I want to do is to create an MSI that puts files into a directory, asks the user for some information, runs a script and then deletes those files without registering an installed program with windows.

In case you're wondering why, it's because I want an MSI that "installs" reports to an SSRS report server.  My current MSI sticks the reports in a directory in Program Files, runs the script to deploy them to a remote report server and then leaves them in the directory with a registered program installed, even though every thing that matters exists on a remote machine.

Is there a way to do what I want with WiX?

Comment: It's unclear why you would use Windows Installer at all when you don't want to install anything on the machine you are running it on.  You might consider using Microsoft's [RS utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/rs-exe-utility-ssrs) directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make windows installer (WiX) always think it is running an upgrade or new install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337209/how-can-i-make-windows-installer-wix-always-think-it-is-running-an-upgrade-or)